# Mean of data.table column values as specified using a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, nearest-neighbor

I have a data.table containing the x,y,z values of 10,000 points (for this example) in the unit cube, and each point has a corresponding attribute (called `P`). I've used `nn2` from the `RANN` package to find the k-neighbors (up to 50) indices of each point  within a radius of 0.075 units from the original data.frame (which is returned as a matrix).

```
library(RANN)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1L) # for reproducible data
DATA <- data.table(runif(10000, 0,1), 
                   runif(10000, 0,1), 
                   runif(10000, 0,1), 
                   runif(10000, 10,30))
colnames(DATA)<-c("x","y","z","P")
nn.idx <- nn2(DATA[,1:3], DATA[,1:3], k=50, 
              treetype = "kd", searchtype = "radius", 
              radius = 0.075)$nn.idx
```

The following `for` loop does the job, but I was wondering if there was any way to speed this up by vectorizing it as this will not scale when applied to >millions of points? Simply put, I want to use `nn.idx` to get the corresponding `P` values from `DATA` and calculate an average `P` that is then assigned to a new column in `DATA` called `mean.P`

```
for(index in 1:nrow(DATA))
  DATA$mean.P[index]<-mean(DATA[nn.idx[index,], P])
```

For illustrative purposes, the following code illustrates what I'm trying to calculate - for all points (grey dots), calculate the mean value for all points (orange + red dots) in a sphere around a given point (red dot) and assign it to that point (red dot). Iterate over all points, but do it in an efficient way that will scale for big data sets.

```
library(rgl)
rgl.open()
rgl.points(DATA[1500,1], DATA[1500,2], DATA[1500,3], color ="red")
rgl.points(DATA[nn.idx[1500,],1:3], color ="orange", add=T)
rgl.points(DATA[,1:3], color ="lightgray", alpha=0.1, add=T)
```

[image]

I have never spent so much time trying to efficiently vectorize one single loop in my life! Also, I'm not opposed to punting and just doing it with c++ and Rcpp but I figured I'd ask here first to see if there was a way in R to make it scale and faster. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it can be handled, memory-wise, with your larger data, you could extract all values at once -`x = DATA[c(nn.idx), P]`- and find the mean by `by = row(nn.idx)[as.logical(nn.idx)]`: `meanP = c(rowsum(x, by)) / tabulate(by)`

Comment: Both solutions thus far seem viable, so I need to test more. Benchmarking them both on a single core of my machine (2016 Dell w/ Xeon E5-2620  2.10GHz), Uwe's solution is fastest at the expense of the second data.table (which did get huge) and bdemarest is adequately faster with a much cheaper vector.

So 1Mil pts and k=100:
`# bdemarest solution;`
`elapsed = 16.22`
and 
`# Uwe solution;`
`elapsed =  4.94`
with corresponding objects of size:
`#  Int_vec  = 8,000,040    long = 1,200,007,392`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that gives nearly a 100-fold speed increase. I don't fully understand why the improvement is so great, but perhaps one of the real data.table experts can comment on that.

```
library(RANN)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1L) # for reproducible data
DATA <- data.table(runif(10000, 0,1), 
                   runif(10000, 0,1), 
                   runif(10000, 0,1), 
                   runif(10000, 10,30))
colnames(DATA)<-c("x","y","z","P")
nn.idx <- nn2(DATA[,1:3], DATA[,1:3], k=50, 
              treetype = "kd", searchtype = "radius", 
              radius = 0.075)$nn.idx

# (1)
# Timing for original loop.
system.time(for(index in 1:nrow(DATA)) {
    DATA$mean.P[index] <- mean(DATA[nn.idx[index,], P])
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   7.830   0.850   8.684 

# (2)
# Use `set()` instead of `$<-` and `[<-`.
system.time({for(index in 1:nrow(DATA)) {
    set(DATA, i=index, j="mean_P_2", value=mean(DATA[nn.idx[index, ], P]))
}})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.405   0.008   3.417
```

As you can see, there is a 2-fold improvement just by substituting the data.table-specific `set()` function in the original loop.

Next, I've tried to put all the functionality into data.table-specific functions (mostly inside the data.table [] syntax). I've also put the `P` values into a vector, because accessing values in vectors is typically much faster than similar operations on data.frames or data.tables.

```
# (3)
# Add row index.
DATA[, row_idx:=seq(nrow(DATA))]

# Isolate P values in a vector, because vector access is cheaper
# than data.table or data.frame access.
P_vec = DATA$P

system.time({
    # Create a list column where each element is a vector of 50 integer indexes.
    DATA[, nn_idx:=lapply(row_idx, function(i) nn.idx[i, ])]
    # Use `:=` and `by=` to internalize the loop within `[.data.table`.
    DATA[, mean_P_3:=mean(P_vec[nn_idx[[1]]]), by=row_idx]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.092   0.002   0.095 

# All results are identical.
all.equal(DATA$mean.P, DATA$mean_P_2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(DATA$mean.P, DATA$mean_P_3)
# [1] TRUE
```

This yields a nearly 100-fold speed increase when compared to the original loop.

It seems to scale pretty well up to 1 million data points:

```
# Try with 1 million data points.
set.seed(1L) # for reproducible data
DATA2 <- data.table(runif(1e6, 0,1), 
                    runif(1e6, 0,1), 
                    runif(1e6, 0,1), 
                    runif(1e6, 10,30))
colnames(DATA2) <- c("x","y","z","P")

system.time({
    nn.idx2 <- nn2(DATA2[,1:3], DATA2[,1:3], k=50, 
                   treetype = "kd", searchtype = "radius", 
                   radius = 0.075)$nn.idx
})
#    user  system elapsed 
# 346.603   1.883 349.708 


DATA2[, row_idx:=seq(nrow(DATA2))]
P_vec = DATA2$P

system.time({
    DATA2[, nn_idx:=lapply(row_idx, function(i) nn.idx2[i, ])]
    DATA2[, mean_P:=mean(P_vec[nn_idx[[1]]]), by=row_idx]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  15.685   0.587  16.297
```

Timings were done on a single core of a 2011 macbook pro (Sandy Bridge 2.2Ghz). RAM usage stayed below 1.5 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `melt()` to reshape the index matrix in long format,  joining, and aggregating:

```
long <- melt(as.data.table(nn.idx)[, pt := .I], measure.vars = patterns("V"))
tmp <- long[DATA[, pt := .I], on = .(value = pt)][, mean(P), by = .(pt)][order(pt), V1]
DATA[, mean.P := tmp][, pt := NULL][]
```

#### Explanation

The index matrix `nn.idx` is converted to a data.table and gains a column `pt` which is the row id of the points. Then the matrix is reshaped from wide to long format.

`tmp` is the vector of mean values of neighbouring points. These are found by right joining `DATA` with `long` to match the indices of the nearest neighbouring points (in column `value`) with the point index appended to `DATA` beforehand.

The last step is to append the result as a new column in `DATA`.

#### Variant 2

Alternatively, the intermediate result can be appended using a second join:

```
long <- melt(as.data.table(nn.idx)[, pt := .I], measure.vars = patterns("V"))
    long[DATA[, pt := .I], on = .(value = pt)][, mean(P), by = .(pt)][DATA, on = "pt"]
```